# Multikeyed Hash: known algorithms?

Tags: hash, hmac, mac, multiparty-computation

A MAC (or HMAC) can be represented by the general formula:

```
MAC = H(key, message)
```

I am calling **"Multikeyed Hash"** the operation (probably there exists already a name for this concept, which I don't know) below:

```
MkHash = H(key1, key2, key3, ...., keyN,  message)
```

Are there known algorithms to compute that? Note that I can't simply concatenate the keys myself, because an attack could be built using the fact that:

```
MkHash = H((key1, key2), key3, ...., keyN,  message)
```

would result in the same `MkHash`.

Comment: Terminology note: an "HMAC" is a specific type of MAC, constructed in a specific way based on a hash function.  You really want the term "MAC" (which is a general type of cryptographical primitive)

Comment: solution with MAC => 7.5, with HMAC => 10  -- I mean, "there is no such thing for HMAC but MAC" is valid answer, but the world will be uglier.

Comment: Your concept of a "multikeyed hash" is missing a key (*ahem*) element: what is it supposed to achieve that a regular MAC doesn't?
 For example, the standard security notion for a MAC is that, if the key is chosen randomly and kept secret from the attacker, the MAC will resist an **adaptive chosen-message existential forgery attack**—even if the attacker is able to obtain lots of message/tag pairs, it should still be costly for them to forge a novel one. But your question gives no guidance on how your "multikeyed hash" is supposed to behave with respect to that or any other model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Are there known algorithms to compute that? Note that I can't simply concatenate the keys

No, you can't just concatenate them, but there are simple modifications to simple concatenation which does make it safe.

The easiest may be to simply prepend the length of every key in the concatination.  That is, if we have:

```
key1, key2, ..., keyN
```

we form the string

```
len(key1) || key1 || len(key2) || key2 || ... || len(keyN) || keyN
```

Where len(X) is a simple encoding of the length; it might be just an n byte encoding of the length (if you know that no key will be longer than $256^n$ bytes long), or you could go fancier and (say) reuse the variable length encoding from DER.

That way, if you introduce any other sequence of keys, you'll generate a distinct string, and so don't run into collision problems.

This is well known, but not greatly discussed (probably because it is assumed to be fairly obvious/trivial).

The only other thing is that you'd need a MAC that takes a variable length key.  Most don't; however one that does is HMAC.  The other possibility is to just use a collision-resistant hash function on the string (and use the result as the real fixed-length MAC key).

Comment: Doesn't your solution (in despite I didn't state as requirement) adds the same risk of key-extension attacks as in a normal MAC?

Comment: @ribamar: now, the standard security definition of a MAC doesn't include related key attacks; on the other hand, the only MAC I can think of with such a vulnerability is HMAC (where appending a 00 byte doesn't change the transform, as long as the key is shorter than the hash block length).  If that's a concern, it's easy to modify the definition of `len` to always include a non-zero byte...